# Creating Dataframe from list of Dictionaries, without using pd.concat()

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have data structures that are dictionaries of numpy arrays, and look something like this:

```
metric_one = 
{0: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
1: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
2: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
3: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])}

metric_two = 
{0: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
1: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
2: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
3: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])}
```

With the following labels:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
```

I'd like to have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   0  1  2  3
a  0  0  0  0
b  1  1  1  1
c  2  2  2  2
d  3  3  3  3
e  4  4  4  4
f  5  5  5  5
g  6  6  6  6
h  7  7  7  7
i  8  8  8  8
j  9  9  9  9
a  0  0  0  0
b  1  1  1  1
c  2  2  2  2
d  3  3  3  3
e  4  4  4  4
f  5  5  5  5
g  6  6  6  6
h  7  7  7  7
i  8  8  8  8
j  9  9  9  9
```

I can do that by converting each of the dictionaries into dataframes and then concatenating them with pd.concat(). However, that is really slow, especially when the dicionaries to concatenate grow (I need to concatenate about 20 of them). From profiling, it seems that creating the single dataframes before concatenating is actually taking the majority of the time. Therefore I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this, for instance rearranging the dictionaries in a smart way into a big data structure that contains all the dictionaries (maybe in a list? maybe in a big dicionary?) so that we can build only one dataframe by passing this big data structure into the constructor.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming

```
metrics = [metric_one, metric_two]
idx = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
```

Using just `numpy`

```
lol = [list(np.concatenate([m[i] for m in metrics])) for i in range(4)]
np.array(lol).T
pd.DataFrame(np.array(lol).T, idx * len(metrics))
```

***naive time test***

[image]

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm and is also much faster!

Answer (score 0):

In case your dictionaries are of the same shape and have the same keys, you can do the following:

```
# setup dummy data
metric_one = {0: np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
    1: np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
    2: np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
    3: np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])}

metric_two = {0: np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
    1: np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
    2: np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
    3: np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])}

labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']

# store metrics in one list to iterate over
dicts = [metric_one, metric_two]

# define helper function to concat numpy arrays
def iter_key(key, dicts):
    return np.concatenate([sub_dict[key] for sub_dict in dicts])

merged = {key: iter_key(key, dicts) for key in metric_one.keys()}

df = pd.DataFrame(merged, index=labels * len(dicts))
print(df)

    0   1   2   3
a   0   0   0   0
b   1   1   1   1
c   2   2   2   2
d   3   3   3   3
e   4   4   4   4
f   5   5   5   5
g   6   6   6   6
h   7   7   7   7
i   8   8   8   8
j   9   9   9   9
a   0   0   0   0
b   1   1   1   1
c   2   2   2   2
d   3   3   3   3
e   4   4   4   4
f   5   5   5   5
g   6   6   6   6
h   7   7   7   7
i   8   8   8   8
j   9   9   9   9
```

Merging the dicts first is faster than concatenating the pandas data frames. Below you'll find timings for 20 dicts:

```
%%timeit
dicts = [metric_one, metric_two]  * 10
def iter_key(key, dicts):
    return np.concatenate([sub_dict[key] for sub_dict in dicts])

merged = {key: iter_key(key, dicts) for key in metric_one.keys()}

df = pd.DataFrame(merged, index=labels * len(dicts))

>>> 1000 loops, best of 3: 630 µs per loop
```

Here the timeit for `concat`:

```
%%timeit
dicts = [metric_one, metric_two]  * 10
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(sub_dict, index=labels) for sub_dict in dicts])

>>> 100 loops, best of 3: 13.6 ms per loop
```

The merge first approach is roughly 20 times faster here.